# Pandas Dataframe fillna() using other known column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following sample `df`:

```
   Other1  Other2     Name Value
0       0       1  Johnson     C
1       0       0  Johnson   NaN
2       1       1    Smith     R
3       1       1    Smith   NaN
4       0       1  Jackson     X
5       1       1  Jackson   NaN
6       1       1  Jackson   NaN
```

I want to be able to fill the `NaN` values with the `df['Value']` value associated with the given name in that row. My desired outcome is the following, which I know can be achieved like so:

```
df['Value'] = df['Value'].fillna(method='ffill')

   Other1  Other2     Name Value
0       0       1  Johnson     C
1       0       0  Johnson     C
2       1       1    Smith     R
3       1       1    Smith     R
4       0       1  Jackson     X
5       1       1  Jackson     X
6       1       1  Jackson     X
```

However, this solution will not achieve the desired result if the names are not followed by one another in order. I also cannot sort by `df['Name']`, as the order is important. Is there an efficient means of simply filling a given `NaN` value by it's associated name value and assigning it to that?

It's also important to note that a given Name will always only have a single value associated with it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `groupby` and `transform`:

```
df['Value'] = df.groupby('Name')['Value'].transform('first')
df

   Other1  Other2     Name Value
0       0       1  Johnson     C
1       0       0  Johnson     C
2       1       1    Smith     R
3       1       1    Smith     R
4       0       1  Jackson     X
5       1       1  Jackson     X
6       1       1  Jackson     X
```

Peter's answer is not correct because the first valid value may not always be the first in the group, in which case `ffill` will pollute the next group with the previous group's value.

ALollz's answer is fine, but `dropna` incurs some degree of overhead.

Comment: Yeah, plus I'd probably also need a drop_duplicates() in the case that a name has multiple instances of the names. This is the way :D.

Comment: Let's say my column name is something other than `Value`, what if it includes a `/` (e.g. 'T/F')? Would I be better off just renaming the column name, or is there a way to reference that column name without a syntax error?

Comment: @rahlf23 see edit. `df.groupby(...)['T/F'].transform`

Comment: Good point re: handling the possibility of a name that has zero valid values. Note that this solution will silently lose data if any name shows up with *multiple* values.

Comment: @coldspeed, you answerd a question 2 weeks ago using df.dot can you share the link. I searched but could not find it

Comment: @pyd see here? https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=dot%20user%3a4909087%20is%3aa

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler good find. Luckily that is not the case for my example, but good to know.